# Error Converting data type nvarchar to bigint in view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a view to number duplicate values. The code is:

```
SELECT  *,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Lookup ORDER BY n) AS rank
FROM   dbo.PENTACIA_PO_QTY
```

Lookup is also a column in the table.

When I want to `CONCAT` the duplicate value eg. `COL.NAME` with the Ranked number i.e

```
TEST1 
TEST2
NAME1
```

it gives me the: `Error Converting data type nvarchar to bigint error.` Why is that?

THE CONCAT CODE:

I tried to do it at the same time as the rank:

```
SELECT  *,CardCode + RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Lookup ORDER BY Lookup) AS rank
FROM   dbo.PENTACIA_PO_QTY`
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code you're using to concatenate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RANK()` returns a `BIGINT` - you can't use operator + to concatenate it to a *CHAR column

You can cast or convert the `RANK()` result to a *char, e.g.

```
SELECT *, 
   CardCode + CAST(RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Lookup ORDER BY Lookup) AS VARCHAR(20)) 
     AS CardPlusRank 
FROM dbo.PENTACIA_PO_QTY;
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Noted that it is unusual to `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` the same thing - AFAIK this will return a `RANK()` of 1 for all values

Comment: I just picked up that's it's not ranking it.. i.e I do not get Test1, Test2, Test3 etc

Comment: I took this from your last edit. `PARTITION BY X ORDER BY Y` where X is the grouping you wish to apply the rank to, and Y determines the actual rank across the set of "X" data. e.g. `PARTITION BY Lookup ORDER BY NAME` etc - you know your data better than I do ;-)